# map_server question

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS and I just want a little background information about map_servers.
I was wondering how do I find a map. Do I have to use programs like GeoServer, MapServer, Google Maps, etc to obtain my map? I have also heard about the SLAM technique that can build a map but I am not really headed that way.  I am more focused on knowing if it is possible to input longitude/latitude values and possibly generate a map from that?

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196438/map_server-question/) by [pikaboo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20658/pikaboo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

map_server reads a single map (it is just a picture) and publish it on a topic or via a service.

what you need is

1. the slam_gmapping node to create a map on base of odometry and laserscan data
   http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping
2. map_saver to save the map (served by gmapping)
3. map_server (to read and publish the saved map) and amcl (to localize your robot in the map)
   http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

you cant just create a map from longitude and latitude values. please read [1.1 image format] at http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

---

Originally posted by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) with karma: 146 on 2014-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2